# Problems with $libdir on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-dump

In short, my question is "why doesn't $libdir work on my PSQL installation."

```
CREATE FUNCTION st_box2d_in(cstring) RETURNS box2d
    AS '$libdir/liblwgeom', 'BOX2DFLOAT4_in'
    LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

yields an error

```
could not access file "$libdir/liblwgeom": No such file or directory
```

while

```
CREATE FUNCTION st_box2d_in(cstring) RETURNS box2d
    AS '/usr/local/pgsql/lib/liblwgeom', 'BOX2DFLOAT4_in'
    LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

works correctly.

The output of

```
% pg_config --pkglibdir
/usr/local/pgsql/lib
```

appears to be correct.

Comment: This should work. Perhaps you are mixing different installations?

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this error as well. I solved it by linking in the PostGIS lib manually to the liblwgeom file, like this:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/postgis/1.5.1/postgres/8.4/lib/postgis-1.5.so 
    /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/lib/liblwgeom
```

I have no idea why PostGIS installs itself in the 'wrong' directory, or why PostgreSQL looks for a file named `liblwgeom` when it seems to be the same file which PostGIS calls `postgis-1.5.so`

All I know is that that seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: Nicely done, I did `ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/postgresql/postgis-1.5` for my installation

Answer (score 1):

**Edited out original reply for it was wrong**

Now that I've looked up postgresql code I have to admit that this string is supposed to be expanded since 2001 ;-). The expansion is very limited though. It only expands `$libdir` followed by directory separator. Still, your output indicates that the string wasn't expanded, because the reported string here is the string actually used for loading library.

That means that substitution failed. Looking at it closer I can see that the expansion only succeeds if target file actually exists. Assuming your directory separator is `/` and `DLSUFFIX` is `.so` and the file `/usr/local/pgsql/lib/liblwgeom.so` actually exists, I have no faintest clue why the hell it fails ;-)

Comment: Why do you say that? This appears to be completely standard usage.

Comment: Joe, your question took me by surprise, I've changed the answer ;-)